# Unable to access custom label value in lightning web componnet

Tags: lightning-web-components, customlabel, js-controller

import labelname from '@salesforce/label/myNamespace.labelName';

Error:

> I was unable to deploy the above statement, Explicit use of namespace "myNamespace" in file "scheduleConfig.js" is prohibited. Use default namespace "c" instead.

when I tried, without namespace this is working fine, but I want to access using namespace

Comment: Do you have a different namespace, why do you want to use a namespace?

Comment: LWC has strong validation for use of namespace, this is one of the instances. 'c.labelName' is recommended.

Comment: if i used c.labelName, able to deploy but at componnet, this is showing error as it does not exist

Comment: I am using namespace as we are doing managed package in org

Comment: It should not matter with your managed package namespace and you should be able to import and use the reference with 'c' namespace 
import labelXYZ from '@salesforce/label/c.labelXYZ';

Comment: '@salesforce/label/c.labelXYZ--this would allow us to delete ,but at output we get error as no such label exists